# Dimension of the moduli space of abelian varieties with a prescribed endomorphism algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, division-algebras

Let $D$ be a division algebra over a number field $K$, and consider abelian varieties $A$ over the complex numbers, of dimension $g$ with an action of (an order of) $D$.  Is it known when this set is non-empty, and if so what is the dimension of this space?

I always thought this was a solved question but glancing over the literature it seems like it might be tricky. Is there a good reference?

Comment: Did you look at Chapter 9 of Birkenake-Lange's book *Complex Abelian Varieties*? Its title is *Moduli spaces of abelian varieties with endomorphism structure*.

Comment: Nope. I found some papers of Oort (say " A construction of an abelian variety with a given endomorphism algebra" https://eudml.org/doc/89907) which seemed to suggest the problem was tricky. Does that chapter answer the question completely?

Comment: Maybe not completely, but there are several interesting examples.